# Nuance of 弱い人 in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I was listening to a podcast discussing how Japanese people spend their time in early January. One of the things they discussed is how they drink sake in the morning. Context:

> 朝十時からみんなでお酒をちょっと飲みます。

then:

> 私の家族はみんな飲めない人。お酒に**弱い人**が多いんだけど...

I roughly translated this into:

> Everyone drinks a little bit of sake from 10AM and onwards.
> Not everyone in my family drinks, **there are people who are weak?**

The last part  of the paragraph is what I am confused about, what are they suggesting here? Are they implying that some people are weak so they keep drinking? I would appreciate some assistance

Comment: `Not everyone in my family drinks` -- みんな飲めない人 means "Everyone is unable to drink", "No one can drink"(全否定), not "Not everyone drinks"(部分否定)

Comment: @chocolate Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

お酒に弱い is just a set phrase for being unable to hold your liquor. The opposite, naturally, is お酒に強い. So one translation of the phrase you pointed out might be:

> お酒に弱い人が多いんだけど... 
> There are many people (in my family) who can't drink, see...